# Lebesgue's differentiation theorem

Tags: analysis

I need to prove that for any locally integrable function $f$ verifies:

$$\lim_{\substack{m(B)\to 0\\x\in B}}{\dfrac{1}{m(B)}\cdot\int_{B}{|f(t)-f(x)|\,dt}}=0,$$

at almost any point $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. I've proved the Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem which says that given a locally integrable function $f$ it is verified that:

$$\lim_{\substack{m(B)\to 0\\x\in B}}{\dfrac{1}{m(B)}\cdot\int_{B}{f(t)\,dt}}=f(x),$$

at almost any point $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Furthermore, as a consequence of the previous result, I know that for any $r\in\mathbb{R}$ it is satisfied that:

$$\lim_{\substack{m(B)\to 0\\x\in B}}{\dfrac{1}{m(B)}\cdot\int_{B}{|f(t)-r|\,dt}}=|f(x)-r|,$$

at almost any point $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. They ask me to prove the first result using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and its countability.

I don't know how to start. Has anyone any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be such that the last limit holds for all rational numbers $r$ (the such $x$ has full measure because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable). Now, if $x \in B$, and $r$ is a rational, for all $t \in B$, $|f(t)-f(x)| \leq |f(x)-r|+|r-f(t)|$. Deduce from this an ($r$-dependent) upper bound on the limsup (of the average of $|f-f(x)|$) and then let $r \rightarrow f(x)$.

Comment: I don't get it. Why use the set of $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the limit above holds for all $r\in\mathbb{Q}$? Why that set is non empty and "big enough"? I don't understand the strategy.

Comment: Well, if the statement held for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ (at a fixed $x$), then we would be done (just take $r=f(x)$). But how can we make sure of that? That’s taking an uncountable intersection of conditions, it’s tricky even from a measure-theoretical viewpoint. So (informally speaking) the best we can do is take the intersection of a countable dense set of conditions (a countable intersection of sets of full measure has full measure) and hope it works.